# Regular Singleton Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Now I am even MORE confused. Am I correct? If not where am I making a mistake? (I am in a village in India with no library facility.)

NBG Definition: A nonempty set X is "Regular” ↔ there is a y ∈ X, such that y ∩ X = ∅. 
Theorem: Every Singleton set {X} is necessarily regular.
Proof. There is only one member X ∈ {X}.  X is necessarily disjoint from every member of X, hency from ANY member of X. QED
Model (found on the internet; unable to locate). Let X be a team of players. Let {X} be a League of teams. Elements of X are players. {X} has only one element, X, which is a team. Hence, necessarily X ∩ {X} = ∅.(No player is a team.) QED

Answer (score 1):

The phrase $y \cap X$ implies either $y$ is a set or that $y \cap X$ makes sense when when y isn't a set.  Both of these are acceptable in set theory where sometimes the entirety of mathematics is constructed from set models.

The proof makes sense.  $X \cap \{X\} = \emptyset$ because the only element of $\{X\}$ is $X$ so if   $X \cap \{X\} \ne \emptyset$ then $X \cap \{X\}=\{X\}$ which would mean $X = \{X\}$ which is not allowed by set axioms.

THe examples of leagues is a good one.  Let  the Detroit Weirdos = {Mathew, Mark, Luke, and John}.  Then Riverdale League = all the teams who signed up to play on Feb 31, 2015 = {the Detroit Weirdos}.  (i.e. the Detroit Weirdos were the only team that signed up to play that date.)

{the detroit weirdos} $\cap $ {Mathew, Mark, Luke, and John} = $\emptyset$.

the detroit weridos is a team.  Mathew, Mark, Luke and John are people.  A team is not a person.